# There has been a critical error on your website. Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to upload a theme onto WordPress and keep getting the error message **There has been a critical error on your website.**

I've checked the error log and this is what I'm receiving.

**Warning: require_once(/home/test/dev.website.com/indus/wp-content/themes/grandrestaurant/lib/custom.lib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/test/dev.website.com/indus/wp-content/themes/grandrestaurant/functions.php on line 23**

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/test/dev.website.com/indus/wp-content/themes/grandrestaurant/lib/custom.lib.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/test/dev.website.com/indus/wp-content/themes/grandrestaurant/functions.php on line 23**

Now, I'm competent but I'm no developer. I'm still very much learning so would appreciate if you could keep it as nooby as possible lol.

Can anyone help me to get this theme installed?

Comment: Seems like at least one file wasn't uploaded to your server or that it got corrupted in the process. Check that the file actually exists (you should be able to find it inside the lib directory) and try uploading this single file again.

Comment: Does `/home/test/dev.website.com/indus/wp-content/themes/grandrestaurant/lib/` match your actual folder/file structure? Alternatively, before you upload the theme, does the `/lib/custom.lib.php` folder and file exist?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The file exists in the themes folder. However, has not been uploaded when I check. Any reasons why this is not uploading and becoming corrupt? I've tried manually uploading the single file but it still does not show up.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. My hosting provider had quarantined the file for some reasons (they wouldn't tell me the reason).